# Does the Ryzen 7 3700U fall under zen1 or zen2 according to gcc?

Tags: kernel, gcc, amd

I am looking into installing the linux-ck kernel, which has architecture specific builds. According to AMD this is a 12nm zen2 chip but if I run `gcc -c -Q -march=native --help=target | grep march` it reports back with `znver1`. I am a little confused by this, my only guess is that its a mobile APU and does not support some of the zen2 features like PCIE4.0. It may not even matter which one I install, but I am very curious as to which one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For me on GCC 9.3.0 it does report `znver2` Probably a version thing.